# Make textarea appear if option selected PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, show-hide

From what I know this question has been ask so I'm so sorry about it, as the title said how do I make text-area appear if option selected in .PHP(file format), so this is my PHP code:

```
    <table>
        <tr class="space">
            <td><label>Warranty :</label></td>
            <td><select name="p_warranty" id="a">
                <option value="">>--------Select One--------<</option>
                <option value="Other" >NO WARRANTY</option>
                <option value="AP WARRANTY">AP WARRANTY</option>
                <option value="FULL WARRANTY">FULL WARRANTY</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr class="space">
            <td><label>Why No Warranty? :</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="p_remark" id="p_remark" type="text" rows="6" cols="65"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and this is my javascript:

```
$("#p_remark").hide();

$( "#a" ).change(function() {
   var val = $("#a").val();
if(val=="Other"){
    $("#p_remark").show();
} else {
    $("#p_remark").hide();
}
});
```

I've test this on jsfiddle and its working fine until I create my PHP and javascript file, its NOT WORKING as it should be, and yeah I do import jquery using CDN

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

What was I missing here?? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb8mnk80/)

Comment: Is your Javascript saved in a `.js` file and pulled into your `.php` file? Or is it in `<script>` tags in your `.php` file?

Comment: i do import jqery using cdn and put it on <head> tag

Comment: I dont see any issue with the code. But one thing to note is we need the script to be executed once dom is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code shoud be executed on DOM ready, so do the following:

```
$(function() {
   ... your code here ...
});
```

end your code coud be optimised to just this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#p_remark").hide();
    $("#a").change(function() {
      $("#p_remark").toggle($(this).val() == "Other");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. @Reflective and @abs are correct about needing to load your jQuery code if you aren't already doing so.

I've attached a screenshot that shows how the code you input into JSFiddle is being loaded for you.

[image: Screenshot of how JSFiddle is loading your javascript]

Comment: yep, JS is executed onLoad in fiddle ... that's a common mistake a begginer should go through

Comment: thanks for letting me know, so its the same as other programming lang :)